# SSH into NAT-configured VMWare VM from another machine

Tags: networking

I have a host machine, and a Linux VM inside it, via VMWare. There VM is configured to use NAT, which I think means the host does not have a separate network interface for the VM.

Is it possible for me to ssh into this VM from some other machine? How do I know which port to use on the host to set up the port forwarding?

I know this might be easier to do if I switch the VM to bridged adapter, but I was wondering if this is possible with NAT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by configuring port forwarding on the NAT network configuration.

You forgot to mention the product you are using, but if it is VMware Workstation Professional then you can set the port forwarding as follows:

- Go to the menu  -> Edit -> Virtual Network Editor
- Select the row with "VMNET8  NAT NAT "
- Click on the button "NAT Settings"
- Button "Add"
- Here you can add the port on your host that you want to accept your SSH on. I would suggest to use something else as 22, so that your host can use SSH if needed. So for example enter 2022 for the host port.
- Add the virtual machine IP address
- Add virtual machine port 22
- Add a description

Click OK

You should now be able to access the VM via SSH by connecting to your host on port 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Also, You can set the default gateway inside the clients.

First, catch the VMware NAT network `default gateway IP address` from this path:

- Main Menu
- Edit
- Virtual Network Editor
- Select `NAT` network
- Click on the button `Nat Setting` and find `Gateway IP`

Second, set this IP address into your VMware machines as a `default gateway address`.